# Adobe Reader: What does "Post" mean when adding a comment?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I'm using Reader 2023.001.20143 64-bit on Win10 Pro.

When I add a comment to a PDF, I see a "Post" option. I didn't try it because I don't know what it does, and I'm wary of what it might do.

So, my question: "What does 'Post' do?"

See image:

[image: PDF comment]

Answer (score 1):

Please see this Adobe article.

[Adobe Comments](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/acrobat/using/commenting-pdfs.html)

**Comments: (for communication between Adobe users using Adobe Cloud Services)**

Note: In Acrobat Reader, complete commenting tools are available only in PDFs that have commenting enabled.  ...   Comments are notes and drawings that communicate ideas or provide feedback for PDFs.

So the PDF you have needs to have comments enabled for you to reply.  That is what "Post" refers to here.

============

**Sticky Notes: (for your own local notes)**

Using Adobe Reader, you can you the Sticky Note feature to add text to a PDF.

Same article:     You can type a text message using the Sticky Note tool. "Post" here means add it to the local document.

============

These are the options you have.

Comment: It appears as though the comment will be posted on adobe cloud or other service for other users to see ("adobe users" vs. "local notes") , but it is not totally clear here.

Comment: I did clarify "between Adobe Cloud users"   Thanks,

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your interpretation of the article. I'm pretty sure I read the article before posting here. I am able to add comments to my document without using the Post button, so comments must be enabled in some sense. The article does **not explain** what "Post" does. In fact, it says **nothing** about "Post" (though it appears in a diagram) or the "cloud" (other than regards reviewers). It says nothing about "communication between Adobe users using Adobe Cloud Services" (other than perhaps implied by interaction among reviewers).

Comment: If comments have been enabled then you can Post them. I did say that in my answer. The article was supporting information and it does support my answer.  Comments have to be enabled in order to post to them.

Comment: From the article:   ......    Note: In Acrobat Reader, complete commenting tools are available only in PDFs that have commenting enabled.   .... This supports my answer